# SQL - How to remove duplicate from joining table

Tags: sql, duplicates

Imagining that you are joining two tables from DB1 and DB2 as follow:

```
SELECT
 DB1.CRE1,
 DB2.CRE2,
 DB2.DAY2
FROM DB1
JOIN DB2 ON DB1.KEY1 = DB2.KEY2
;
```

The result that I am getting is something like below:

```
DB1.CRE1---DB2.CRE2---DB2.DAY2
CRE1_A-----CRE2_A-----SEP01
CRE1_A-----CRE2_A-----SEP02
...
```

What you see above is that 1 value of DB1.CRE1 matches multiple values of DB2.CRE2 because there are different dates associate with the same DB2.CRE2.
I'm looking for a solution to:
- Match the 2 table as per given condition DB1.KEY1 = DB2.KEY2, and;
- Eliminate the duplicate values from DB2.CRE2 and only take the first earliest date (DB2.DAY2) associated with DB2.CRE2, such as SEP01 in the above sample.

Not sure if this is possible but hope to have your helps.

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a `WHERE` clause with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT DB1.CRE1, DB2.CRE2, DB2.DAY2
FROM DB1 JOIN
     DB2
     ON DB1.KEY1 = DB2.KEY2
WHERE DB2.DAY2 = (SELECT MIN(D2.DAY2)
                  FROM DB2 D2
                  WHERE D2.KEY2 = DB2.KEY2
                 );
```

The subquery calculates the minimum `DAY2` for each `KEY2`. 
 The outer query only returns the row that matches that `DAY2` for each `KEY2`.

Comment: Hi Gordon,

Your solution works, but may I have your explanation on the WHERE clause of the subquery?

Thanks!

Comment: Also Gordon, I noticed that there are many result that were removed. Let's say I got 10 results before the change with 4 results with duplication. After the change, I only got 1-2 results. Do you know why?

Comment: @TonyNguyen . . . You may need to set up a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: what is the purpose of this set up?